# Gráfico baseado em dados semanais

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Colegas programadores, boa noite. Estou com dificuldades em **como** montar um gráfico de registros semanais utilizando PHP, MySQL e a biblioteca Highcharts.

Possuo registros de conexões e desconexões, no qual é salvo no formato *2017-03-30 16:43:04*, porém no gráfico em linhas preciso exibir  essas informações em um período de 7 dias.

Por exemplo com o início da semana no dia de hoje: o eixo das abscissas conteria 7 valores **03/04, 04/04, 05/04, 06/04, 07/04, 08/04 e 09/04** e o eixo das ordenadas possuiria valores inteiros que representam uma certa quantidade de conexão ou desconexão.

Não estou conseguindo saber como montar esses dados no lado do backend, principalmente a query SQL.

Edit: esqueci de colocar a imagem e os dados da tabela...

---

Colunas da tabela:

`id | username | event | date`

Onde **id** é o id do evento, **username** o nome do usuário, **event** pode assumir valores de conexão ou desconexão e **date** é a data no formato *2017-03-30 16:43:04*.

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

você deve executar um SELECT fazendo uma contagem de registros de conexão, de desconexão, uni-los em colunas separadas e por fim soma-los, exemplo:

```
mysql> select * from evento;
+----------+------------+------------+
| username | event      | date       |
+----------+------------+------------+
| joao     | conexao    | 2017-04-04 |
| joao     | desconexao | 2017-04-04 |
| maria    | conexao    | 2017-04-05 |
| maria    | desconexao | 2017-04-05 |
| joao     | conexao    | 2017-04-06 |
| joao     | desconexao | 2017-04-07 |
| ana      | conexao    | 2017-04-07 |
| ana      | desconexao | 2017-04-07 |
| pedro    | conexao    | 2017-04-05 |
| pedro    | desconexao | 2017-04-06 |
| carla    | conexao    | 2017-04-07 |
| carla    | desconexao | 2017-04-07 |
| felipe   | conexao    | 2017-04-07 |
| felipe   | desconexao | 2017-04-08 |
+----------+------------+------------+
14 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select x.date, sum(x.qtde_conexao) qtde_conexao, sum(x.qtde_desconexao) qtde_desconexao
    -> from (
    -> select date, count(1) qtde_conexao, 0 qtde_desconexao
    -> from evento
    -> where event='conexao'
    -> group by date
    -> union all
    -> select date, 0, count(1)
    -> from evento
    -> where event='desconexao'
    -> group by date) x
    -> group by x.date;
+------------+--------------+-----------------+
| date       | qtde_conexao | qtde_desconexao |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 2017-04-04 |            1 |               1 |
| 2017-04-05 |            2 |               1 |
| 2017-04-06 |            1 |               1 |
| 2017-04-07 |            3 |               3 |
| 2017-04-08 |            0 |               1 |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```